# Experience with integrating PayPal and Sharetribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, sharetribe

I am trying to set up PayPal with Sharetribe and to set up a sandbox environment. There seems to be no documentation on this.

Steps I've done:

1. create account in https://developer.paypal.com/
2. create Application
3. ask PayPal to enable ChannelInitiatedBilling in adaptive payments (I'm currently waiting for a response)
4. create sandbox accounts via developer.paypal.com
5. set up my `config.yml` with Paypal access data (using business account).

   - `note:` Secure Merchant Account ID is `paypal_partner_id`.

Has anyone configured Sharetribe with PayPal successfully?

Comment: I decide write down step by step how to configure Sharetribe with PayPal: http://publish.yexperiment.com/post/156715320289/sharetribe-with-paypal-payments-the-lost

Answer (score 0):

From [#1462](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe/issues/1462) The open source version of the sharetribe has the same source code as the hosted version, but due to the agreement with PayPal, using the PayPal integration is not possible with the open source version.

Implementing your own payment gateway(adaptive_payment) will be a lot easier. ChannelInitiatedBilling is not required for paypal adaptive payment.

You can create a new service like 'paypal_adaptive_service' similar to 'paypal_service' or create a new TransactionProcess with a new process to do adaptive payment method.